# Multiple IPs for customer in Plesk 11

Tags: web-hosting, ip-address, shared-hosting, plesk

First of all, please forgive me if my question sounds dumb, as I'm not very skilled in sys admin...

For a shared web hosting plan, my host (which is a reseller) used to provide 3 different IPs for a given subscribed account, which would be used in Plesk 9.5.

However, they are migrating to Plesk 11 and now provide only 1 IP, saying they no longer can provide several IPs, because of technical restriction due to the new Plesk.

Are you aware of a solution to this problem I could suggest to my hosting company? Feel free to ask for more information if needed, I'll transmit the request to them.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. On the contrary, I think this question is on the right site, as I'm looking for a solution to suggest to my host to implement. It's a (quite) small company and I can easily transfer information to the server admins. If you don't agree though, I'll make the move to the webmasters site.

Comment: You could always ask them to split your account into 2 subscriptions and discount 100% on one of them each month and that way plesk can give you 2 ips, the problem is multiple IP's on one account and that needs to be altered, I don't have the solution for you but I've heard of this before but to be honest it shouldn't be your job to resolve it. If they can't work it out, or they don't seem to care, or they just say it cant be done then its worth changing provider :P

Answer (score 1):

When configuring a new subscription, the IP Address is available in a dropdown to me.

We only have one IP on our Plesk 11 server, but it appears I can configure a new IP under:

- Tools & Settings

  - Tools & Resources

    - IP Addresses.

This is all controlled via the Administrator account. The documentation (http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/59410.htm) regarding IP Pools indicates that the IPs can be assigned to customer accounts as well.

Of course the hosting provider would also need to assign this IP to your server.

Comment: So basically your hosting provider is smoking crack :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Pushed the info to the provider, now waiting for them. Didn't ask about crack though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no doubt that Plesk 11 can support multiple ip addresses and it is quite possible to add them via Tools & Settings as it was mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, the hosting provider also confirmed it previously. The problem is that there is a 1 subscription = 1 IP relationship. So in order to get several IPs one has to subscribe to several plans. The provider is still looking for a solution.